# C# DateTime to Javascript DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the following code to pass to my javascript code

```
sb.Append("start: new Date(" + Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.AppointmentDate).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "),");
```

The problem is that it's not including the time along with the date. How can I include the time as well?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) can be co-opted to do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably regional settings, try:

```
sb.Append("start: new Date(" + Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.AppointmentDate).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat) + "),");
```

Comment: No luck. I'm getting dates like this: new Date(1288260000000)

Comment: Se my answer below, `new Date(<number you got>)` The number is the milliseconds. The above  should work by the way, try pasting this in your url bar: `javascript:alert(new Date(1288260000000) )`

Comment: @Mike are you sure your AppointmentDate is correct? All the examples given and the one you gave yourself should have at least some kind of time component in it.

Comment: You're right. I am getting the time component with it. I tested it in the firebug console. I guess the javascript isn't translating it correctly on the client side. At least I know the problem isn't on the server side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse date/time string which is in `en-US` format.

Put this code in your aspx page into the SCRIPT tag and you will have your `DateTime` value in `dt` variable.

```
var dtString = '<%= MyDateTimeObject.ToString((new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).DateTimeFormat) %>';

var dt = new Date(dtString );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime? myTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

        Console.Write(myTime.Value.ToUnixTimeInMs().ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    private static readonly DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    public static double ToUnixTimeInMs(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.Subtract(DateTimeExtensions.unixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Simply pass the return value of `ToUnixTimeInMs()` into the constructor of a JavaScript Date object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .NET 3.5+ or the [AJAX Extensions for .NET 2.0](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=77296), you may already have the methods you need to convert objects to JavaScript in the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287.aspx) class.

Add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

...

var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsDate = jsSerializer.Serialize(appointment.AppointmentDate);
```

Now, on the JS side, you're going to have to undo the JSON serialization using a [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Date.parse that can handle many more formats.

```
var d = new Date(Date.parse("<your date here>"));
```

You need to use new Date and Date.parse because Date.parse does not return a date object but number of milliseconds since 1970 nnn something.